# How to write inside a dictionary entry in NSUserDefaults without using temporary variables?

Tags: swift, dictionary, nsuserdefaults

I have this code:

```
var address = Dictionary<String, AnyObject?>();
address["address1"] = "Here";
address["address2"] = "There";
...
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults();
var data = defaults.valueForKey("active_user")! as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject?>
data["address"] = address;
defaults.setValue(data, forKey: "active_user");
defaults.synchronize();
```

I want to change it into like this:

```
var address = Dictionary<String, AnyObject?>();
address["address1"] = "Here";
address["address2"] = "There";
...
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults();
defaults["active_user"]!["address"]! = address;
defaults.synchronize();
```

Is this possible? How can I do that?

Comment: I know you've selected an answer already but I think you might like my solution, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhat possible by extending NSUserDefaults to have a subscript. See below:

```
extension NSUserDefaults {

    subscript(key: String) -> Any {

        get {

            return value(forKey: key)
        }

        set {

            setValue(newValue, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

This can then be used like so:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

defaults["myKey"] = "someValue"

let myValue = defaults["myKey"]
```

One limitation is that you won't be able to modify nested collections as you've done in your example. You'll always have to make a manual assignment back to the user defaults object to save something.

```
// this won't work
defaults["active_user"]!["address"]! = address; 

// do this instead
let user = defaults["active_user"]! 
user["address"] = address
defaults["active_user"] = user
```

Edit:

I figured out a way to overload the subscript so you *can* modify nested collections, with slightly different but very clean syntax. Only works at one level of nesting, but I think it could be taken further. Add this to your `NSUserDefaults` extension:

```
subscript(firstKey: String, secondKey: String) -> Any? {

    get {

        if let dict = value(forKey: firstKey) as? [String: Any] {

            return dict[secondKey]
        }

        return nil
    }

    set {

        if let dict = value(forKey: firstKey) as? [String: Any] {

            dict[secondKey] = newValue

            setValue(dict, forKey: firstKey)
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
defaults["active_user", "address"] = "some address"

let address = defaults["active_user", "address"]
```

Comment: Hey this is awesome! I was just recently know about subscript, but it never occurred in my mind to use multiple parameter in the subscript, even though I know that could be done! Many many thanks!!